# synchronize two methods and avoid to run simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading

class1 has two methods, do1 and do2.
It is instanciated from multiple thread in the same application.

i need to synchronize two methods with this specs:

do1 can be executed only from 1 thread at time, lock would be a good solution.

do2 can be called from multiple thread at the same time but 
it cannot be called when do1 is running.

When do1 is called evary thread must wait the completion of do1 before to start do2.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` - have you looked into that?

Comment: if it is a real project, not a school one, take a look at my post.
http://pilpag.blogspot.dk/2016/04/advanced-programming-easy-way-to-manage.html

Comment: you need to have a critical zone on both A and B, but the lock has to work on the same object. so you need to get it in a thread safe operation

Comment: it's a real application, a windows service working on sql server database, i'm trying to remove some deadlock it happens when one thread is reading from a table and other thread are updading the same table. MAny updates at the same time does'nt cause the deadlock but one update at the same time of a read can cause the deadlock @MatiasCicero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways to accomplish this.  One is with a Semaphore with one method that takes all available slots with one method, and another that uses one slot per execution attempt.  That's a bit of a hack, though, what you really need is a synchronization object that allows exclusive and non-exclusive locks.

That's what `ReaderWriterLock` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim` do.  They're designed for cases where you need exclusive write access to a resource but non-exclusive read access to the resource, and work well for these sort of scenarios:

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim m_lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public string do2()
{
    m_lock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        // Do work, many threads can enter this lock at the same time
    }
    finally
    {
        m_lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

public void do1()
{
    m_lock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        // Do work, only one thread can be in here at once
    }
    finally
    {
        m_lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the problem can be solved by simply using a private static lock object to synchronize the methods, which can be done as follows.

```
public class c1
{
    private static iLock = new object();

    public void do1()
    {
        lock (iLock)
        {
          // actual method body
        }
    }

    public void do2()
    {
        lock (iLock)
        {
          // actual method body
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution synchronize do2 too, if no one is calling do1, do2 can be called simultaneously.